# Install docker on RedHatLinux 6.7

Tags: docker

I am following the documentation https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/rhel/ to install docker on RHEL 6.7. 
When I run the command

```
sudo yum install docker-engine
```

I get the following error

```
Error: Package: docker-engine-1.9.1-1.el7.centos.x86_64 (dockerrepo)
           Requires: libsystemd-journal.so.0(LIBSYSTEMD_JOURNAL_196)(64bit)
Error: Package: docker-engine-1.9.1-1.el7.centos.x86_64 (dockerrepo)
           Requires: libsystemd-journal.so.0(LIBSYSTEMD_JOURNAL_195)(64bit)
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

As per the suggestion I tried to run the command

```
sudo yum install docker-engine --skip-broken
```

Here is the output

```
    Packages skipped because of dependency problems:
    audit-libs-python-2.3.7-5.el6.x86_64 from RHEL-67-x86_64
    docker-engine-1.9.1-1.el7.centos.x86_64 from dockerrepo
    docker-engine-selinux-1.9.1-1.el7.centos.noarch from dockerrepo
    libsemanage-python-2.0.43-5.1.el6.x86_64 from RHEL-67-x86_64
    policycoreutils-python-2.0.83-24.el6.x86_64 from RHEL-67-x86_64
    setools-libs-3.3.7-4.el6.x86_64 from RHEL-67-x86_64
    setools-libs-python-3.3.7-4.el6.x86_64 from RHEL-67-x86_64
```

How can I fix above problems and install docker on RHEL 6.7 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below steps do work for Docker to be installed on OEL 6.10 with a user having super user privileges.

1. Create a user with SUDO Access as suggested in Red-Hat Docs ([Link][1] speaks well on this process). For instance I created an user as docker with group as docker.

   ```
   groupadd docker  
   useradd -m -g docker docker
   ```
2. Add docker repository for installing latest copy of Docker for RHEL/Centos 6

   ```
   yum update -y  
   yum install epel-release  
   vi /etc/yum.repos.d/docker.repo
   ```
3. Add below contents to /etc/yum.repos.d/docker.repo

   ```
   [docker-repo]  
   name=Docker Repo  
   baseurl=https://yum.dockerproject.org/repo/main/centos/6/  
   enabled=1  
   gpgcheck=1  
   gpgkey=https://yum.dockerproject.org/gpg
   ```
4. Switch to "docker" user and execute below commands:

   `sudo yum install -y docker-engine`
5. Post Installation start docker using below commands.

   ```
   sudo chkconfig docker on  

   sudo service docker start  
   Starting cgconfig service:                                 [  OK  ]  
   Starting docker:                                           [  OK  ]  

   sudo service docker status  
   docker (pid  26925) is running...  

   ps -ef | grep docker  
   root     25590 14123  0 Jul27 ?        00:00:00 sshd: docker [priv]  
   docker   25594 25590  0 Jul27 ?        00:00:00 sshd: docker@pts/1  
   docker   25595 25594  0 Jul27 pts/1    00:00:00 -bash  
   root     26925     1  2 00:00 pts/1    00:00:00 /usr/bin/docker -d  
   docker   27106 25595  0 00:00 pts/1    00:00:00 ps -ef  
   docker   27107 25595  0 00:00 pts/1    00:00:00 grep docker  

   docker ps -a  
   CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
   ```

   [1]: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux_OpenStack_Platform/2/html/Getting_Started_Guide/ch02s03.html

Comment: It's worth mentioning that docker user should be in sudoers to be able to run sudo commands

Answer (score 6):

RHEL 6 is no longer supported by Docker, the latest version you can install is Docker 1.7.  The installation instructions can be found [here](https://docs.docker.com/v1.7/installation/rhel/#red-hat-enterprise-linux-6.5-installation)

Comment: Thanks for the reply.

Comment: To top it off, things like selinux seem to interfere a lot with this 6.x RHEL and Docker 1.7... There are some policies that must be entered that might resolve the issue, but most likely won't resolve it. I couldn't figure it out. (unfortunately, there are hosts out there that don't provide RHEL 7 if you can believe it).

Comment: It works with RedHat 6.9 Santiago.                                                    
`Containers: 0
Images: 0
Storage Driver: devicemapper
 Pool Name: docker-253:0-130948-pool
 Pool Blocksize: 65.54 kB
 Backing Filesystem: extfs
 Data Space Used: 305.7 MB
 Data Space Total: 107.4 GB
 Data Space Available: 107.1 GB
... Udev Sync Supported: true
 Deferred Removal Enabled: false
 Library Version: 1.02.117-RHEL6 (2016-12-13)
Execution Driver: native-0.2
Logging Driver: json-file
Kernel Version: 2.6.32-696.18.7.el6.x86_64
CPUs: 2
Total Memory: 3.743 GiB`

Answer (score 1):

You can install the last version of Docker by upgrading your Kernel to 3.10. At your own risk :)

Worked for me and pretty stable for weeks now.

[Upgrading RHEL Kernel](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Deployment_Guide/ch-Manually_Upgrading_the_Kernel.html)

Comment: But doesn't it require `systemd`?

Answer (score 1):

For me was useful this [link](https://foxutech.com/how-to-install-docker-on-centos/). I have an oracle server 6.10 and the steps are:

- add epel packages: `rpm -iUvh http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/x86_64/epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm`
- update packages: `yum update -y`
- Install docker: `yum install docker-io -y`
- Start service: `/etc/init.d/docker start`
- Configure service in start machine: `chkconfig docker on`