# Installing docker on redhat linux - issue with 'container-selinux' and 'selinux-policy'

Tags: linux, docker, containers, redhat

I have Linux on EC2 and trying to install Docker.
How to resolve issue with 'container-selinux' and 'selinux-policy'?

```
lsb_release -d
Description:    Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.9 (Santiago)

sudo rpm -i container-selinux-2.9-4.el7.noarch.rpm
warning: container-selinux-2.9-4.el7.noarch.rpm: Header V3 RSA/SHA256 Signature, key ID f4a80eb5: NOKEY
error: Failed dependencies:
    selinux-policy >= 3.13.1-39 is needed by container-selinux-2:2.9-4.el7.noarch
    selinux-policy-base >= 3.13.1-39 is needed by container-selinux-2:2.9-4.el7.noarch
    selinux-policy-targeted >= 3.13.1-39 is needed by container-selinux-2:2.9-4.el7.noarch
```

Comment: Do you have access to the RHEL-6.9 repos ?

Comment: Is any particular? how to check that?

Comment: Why are you trying to install `container-selinux` using `rpm` and not using `Yum` ? You can try `yum --enablerepo=* install container-selinux`. This will resolve dependencies. If not, post the output of the above command.

Comment: Just tried that (sudo yum --enablerepo=* install container-selinux) got this error `No package container-selinux available.`

Comment: One thing I just noticed that, your RHEL version is `6.9` and you are using `el7` rpm. `el7` rpms are for RHEL-7. Anyways, since you don't have access to the repos, you have to download the dependencies to a local directory and then execute `rpm -Uvh *.rpm`.

Comment: Ok, do you mind showing exact commands on how to download dependencies that are needed?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160221/discussion-between-iamauser-and-joe).

Comment: I was trying to do `sudo yum install docker-ce` and got a `No package container-selinux available`.  I got container-selinux installed by running this command (from [this page](https://github.com/docker/for-linux/issues/299)): `sudo yum install -y http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7/extras/x86_64/Packages/container-selinux-2.42-1.gitad8f0f7.el7.noarch.rpm`

Answer (score 3):

```
sudo yum --enablerepo=* install container-selinux
```

did the trick for me on Oracle Linux 7.4.

After the installation I could `yum install docker-ce`.

Answer (score 0):

Red Hat doesn't provide docker packages for RHEL6, only for RHEL7. See [Does Red Hat provide docker for RHEL 6?](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/1378023)

If using RHEL7 is not an option for you, then the only way to get Docker on RHEL6 is to use packages from Docker, Inc., but then you won't have support from Red Hat. See this question: [Install docker on RedHatLinux 6.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34930874/install-docker-on-redhatlinux-6-7).