# Can't install docker on amazon linux instance

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, docker

My instance is on this AMI: `amzn2-ami-hvm-2.0.20191116.0-x86_64-gp2 (ami-01f14919ba412de34)`
I want to install docker following this [document](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/docker-basics.html#install_docker) so here is the output of my commands:

```
[ec2-user@ip-10-193-192-42 ~]$ sudo amazon-linux-extras install docker
Installing docker
Loaded plugins: extras_suggestions, langpacks, priorities, update-motd
Cleaning repos: amzn2-core amzn2extra-docker docker-ce-stable
12 metadata files removed
6 sqlite files removed
0 metadata files removed
Loaded plugins: extras_suggestions, langpacks, priorities, update-motd
amzn2-core                                               | 2.4 kB     00:00
amzn2extra-docker                                        | 1.3 kB     00:00
docker-ce-stable                                         | 3.5 kB     00:00
(1/6): amzn2-core/2/x86_64/group_gz                        | 2.6 kB   00:00
(2/6): amzn2-core/2/x86_64/updateinfo                      | 174 kB   00:00
(3/6): docker-ce-stable/x86_64/updateinfo                  |   55 B   00:00
(4/6): docker-ce-stable/x86_64/primary_db                  |  37 kB   00:00
(5/6): amzn2extra-docker/2/x86_64/primary_db               |  59 kB   00:00
(6/6): amzn2-core/2/x86_64/primary_db                      |  36 MB   00:00
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package docker.x86_64 0:18.09.9ce-2.amzn2 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: runc = 1.0.0 for package: docker-18.09.9ce-2.amzn2.x8                                                                                        6_64
--> Processing Dependency: containerd = 1.2.6 for package: docker-18.09.9ce-2.am                                                                                        zn2.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: pigz for package: docker-18.09.9ce-2.amzn2.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libcgroup for package: docker-18.09.9ce-2.amzn2.x86_6                                                                                        4
--> Running transaction check
---> Package containerd.io.x86_64 0:1.2.10-3.2.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: container-selinux >= 2:2.74 for package: containerd.i                                                                                        o-1.2.10-3.2.el7.x86_64
---> Package libcgroup.x86_64 0:0.41-21.amzn2 will be installed
---> Package pigz.x86_64 0:2.3.4-1.amzn2.0.1 will be installed
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: containerd.io-1.2.10-3.2.el7.x86_64 (docker-ce-stable)
           Requires: container-selinux >= 2:2.74
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
Installation failed. Check that you have permissions to install.
[ec2-user@ip-10-193-192-42 ~]$
```

How to get this work?

**EDIT**

My instance is in an Autoscaling GRoup so I terminated the previous one and I tried to do docker install in the new one:

I got to install docker but when I run the command:

```
sudo service docker start
```

I logged out from the instance and I got an error window:

```
network error: software caused connection abort
```

Any clue why is this happening ?

Comment: `Requires: container-selinux >= 2:2.74` try installing this package first using `yum install -y container-selinux >= 2:2.74`

Comment: `[ec2-user@ip-10-193-192-42 ~]$ sudo yum install -y container-selinux >= 2:2.74
Error: Nothing to do`

Comment: I will recomend docker-optmized-ECS-AMI for running docker.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47579041/installing-docker-on-redhat-linux-issue-with-container-selinux-and-selinux

Comment: @error404 please check the edit part of the question. In fact I get to install Docker but then I lose connection to the instance and I can't ssh into it now after running docker start service

Comment: you don't have permissions here "Installation failed. Check that you have permissions to install."

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Just tried to install Docker to the exact same AMI and all went well. I guess you’re experiencing issues because of extra repo named docker-ce-stable. You don’t need it on Amazon Linux 2 AMI, so, as soon as you got SSH access to your new instance, execute:

```
sudo amazon-linux-extras install docker
```

and you should be ok.

Comment: Same happened to me, if you were following docker docs, just delete the repo and run that command.
To delete repo if you're a newbie : sudo rm /etc/yum.repos.d/docker-ce.repo

Comment: Holy moly. That was my problem apparently. Thanks @rancor

Comment: Yes this was the problem, smh. I was installing the normal way on Linux

Comment: @Rancor thanks. it worked here. most people get here AFTER following Docker instructions

Comment: I don't know if some other instructions or scripts have changed, but I found what I needed to delete was: /etc/yum.repos.d/download.docker.com_linux_centos_7_x86_64_stable.repo

Answer (score 4):

got the same problem, but fixed with different way.

Check in your Amazon Linux 2 box, if there is a file name

```
/etc/yum.repos.d/docker-ce
```

You should delete it. Then it would be fine to run the install command

```
sudo amazon-linux-extras install docker
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use cloud-init to set up the Docker for you as part of the setup.  Terraform makes it easy to implement as well

This is [the bit from my Terraform module](https://github.com/trajano/terraform-docker-swarm-aws/blob/d9b9678c450a54abfa95c7aee4be868fea9b9691/common.cloud-config#L1-L5) that would set up Docker for you using cloud-init.

Note this is on Amazon Linux 3 which includes the `amzn2extra-docker` repo by default.

```yaml
#cloud-config
repo_update: true
repo_upgrade: all
packages:
  - docker
```

In addition I recommend these lines

```yaml
manage_resolve_conf: true
resolve_conf:
  name_servers: [ '169.254.169.253' ]
```

The default DNS is in the same subnet as your host machine which *may* happen to be the subnet that Docker may create it's containers in thus making life a bit awkward.